# Uimageview Multiple

Tags: iphone, ios6

How do I set multiple custom Ui image views on a single page, ability for the user to select the images from there camera roll. Have not really seen this being done before on any tutorial websites, was hoping someone would know wgat to do here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is to use the UIButton and set the image in it.

This gives you the baked in functionality of touch for the view and makes it very easy to know which button/image was pressed.

Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading into UICollectionViews. This is exactly what they are used for. Each cell would be tappable which could in turn bring up a UIImagePicker to select a different image for that cell by utilizing cellForRowAtIndexPath. Check out a few [tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12)